# Storing and displaying JSON data with MongoDB and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and AngularJS and unfortunately I don't know how to search for my problem.
I have a schema like this:

```
var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    "categoryID": Number,
    "questionString": String,
    "answerA" : String,
    "answerB" : String,
    "answerC" : String,
    "answerD" : String,
    "correctAnswer": String,
    "author": Number,
    "isCertified": {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    "created": {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

I then want to display the JSON data with AngularJS in a table:

```
<tr class="list" ng-repeat="q in questions">
    <td class="list">{{ q._id }}</td>
    <td class="list">{{ q.categoryID }}</td>
    <td class="list">{{ q.questionString }}</td>
    <td class="list">{{ q.answerA }}</td>
    <td class="list">{{ q.answerB }}</td>
    <td class="list">{{ q.answerC }}</td>
    <td class="list">{{ q.answerD }}</td>
    <td class="list">{{ q.correctAnswer }}</td>
    <td class="list">{{ q.author }}</td>
    <td class="list">
</tr>
```

My JSON data looks like this:

```
{
    "questionString": "What is the sense of life?",
    "categoryID: "2",
    "author": "1",
    "answerA": "I am answer A",
    "answerB": "I am answer B",
    "answerC": "I am answer C",
    "answerD": "I am answer D",
    "correctAnswer": "3"
  }
```

Although that works, it is not exactly what I want. I want to have another collection for the category and the author so that I could do something like `{{ q.author.authorName }}` and `{{ q.category.categoryName }}` which should display the author/category name depending on its ID. What is the best practice to store the data like this?

It would be great to define something like this:

```
var categories = [
    {"catID": "1", "catString" : "General"},
    {"catID": "2", "catString" : "Games"},
    {"catID": "3", "catString" : "Movies"}
];
```

Another question: would there be a better way to store the answers and the corresponding correctAnswer?

Comment: Can you share your object ? Paste your complete object.

Comment: Do you mean the JSON file?

Comment: yeah, your json object. it will help me to debug

Comment: I edited my question. However, I'm currently using Postman and MongoDb locally only.

Answer (score 0):

These seems like a case of one-to-many relationship in mongodb. You can look at the link: [one-to-many](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)

You have to create an authors collection and reference it by its id in other collections:

For instance:

```
{
  _id: 'authors'
  author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf"]
}
```

In the case of mongoose, you can use ObjectId to refer to Authors inside your Questions schema:

```
authors: {
  type: Schema.ObjectId, 
  ref: 'authors'
}
```